# PyCharm Error no module named pydanticcore._pydantic_core

Tags: pycharm, pydantic

I have several scripts that suddenly stopped working - in fact ALL Python scripts no longer compile in PyCharm.  One second they were running without issue and the next I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'
```

I tried reinstalling pydantic, pydanticcore, and I verified both were in the correct folder in Python.  I added the modules to my requirements list, using pip show to verify the version:

```
pydantic==2.6.4
pydantic-core==2.16.3
```

No love.

I am running directly off my Windows laptop so there is no virtualization issue AND I have no clue why the entire IDE would suddenly crash.

I also rebooted, uninstalled and reinstalled pydantic and pydantic-core and I am NOT directly referencing or using them anywhere.  .

***I figured out how to go to the Interpreter and manually added in pydantic.  Now it is asking for regex and regex_core (core I cannot find).  Why did all of my modules suddenly vanish?***

Has anybody ever experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I had used PyCharm to directly install a missing module but I never installed that module in my host system.  I had to go through all modules I added until I found the missing one.  Once I had installed the missing module in the host system, everything worked great!